# Convert Date Stored as NUMERIC to DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am currently working on a query that needs to calculate the difference in days between two different dates. I've had issues with our `DATE` columns before, because they are all being stored as `numeric` columns which is a complete pain.

I tried using `CONVERT` as I had done in the past to try and get the different pieces of the `DATETIME` string built, but I am not having any luck.

The commented line `--convert(datetime,)` is where I am having the issue. Basically, I need to convert `PO_DATE` and `LINE_DOCK_DATE` to a format that is usable, so I can calculate the difference between the two in days.

```
USE BWDW

GO

SELECT 

  [ITEM_NO]
  ,[ITEM_DESC]
  ,[HEADER_DUE_DATE]
  ,[BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblDimWhs].WHS_SHORT_NAME AS 'Warehouse'
  ,[BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl].[PO_NO] AS 'PO NUMBER'
  ,[BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl].[PO_DATE] AS 'Start'
  ,[BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl].[PO_STATUS] AS 'Status'
  ,[BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl].[LINE_DOCK_DATE] AS 'End'
  --,(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), [BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl].[PO_DATE])) FROM dbo.DS_tblFactPODtl)


FROM [BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl] 
INNER JOIN [BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblDimWhs] ON [BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl].WAREHOUSE = [BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblDimWhs].WAREHOUSE
INNER JOIN [BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblFactPO] ON [BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl].PO_NO = [BWDW].    [dbo].[DS_tblFactPO].PO_NO
WHERE [BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl].[PO_STATUS] = 'Closed'
AND [BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl].[LINE_DOCK_DATE] <> 0
```

I have a snippet I saved from a previous project I worked on that needed to only display results from today through another year.  That had a bunch of CAST and CONVERTS in it, but I tried the same methodology with no success.

In the long run, I want to add a column to each database table to contain a proper `datetime` column that is usable in the future... but that is another story. I have read numerous posts on stackoverflow that talk about converting to NUMERIC and such, but nothing out of a NUMERIC back to `DATETIME`.

Example data:

```
Start    | End      | Difference
--------------------------------
20110501 | 20111019 | 171
20120109 | 20120116 | 7
20120404 | 20120911 | 160
```

Just trying to calculate the difference..

MODIFIED PER AARON:

```
SELECT
  FPODtl.[ITEM_NO] AS [Item]
  ,FPODtl.[ITEM_DESC] AS [Description] 
  ,D.WHS_SHORT_NAME AS [Warehouse]
  ,FPODtl.[PO_NO] AS [PO NUMBER]
  ,FPODtl.[PO_DATE] AS [Start]
  ,FPODtl.[PO_STATUS] AS [Status]
  ,FPODtl.[LINE_DOCK_DATE] AS [End]
  ,DATEDIFF
  (
    DAY,
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(CONVERT(CHAR(8), FPODtl.PO_DATE)) = 1
      THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), FPODtl.PO_DATE)) END,
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(CONVERT(CHAR(8), FPODtl.[LINE_DOCK_DATE])) = 1
      THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), FPODtl.[LINE_DOCK_DATE])) END
  )
    FROM [dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl] AS FPODtl 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DS_tblDimWhs] AS D 
  ON FPODtl.WAREHOUSE = D.WAREHOUSE
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DS_tblFactPO] AS FPO 
  ON FPODtl.PO_NO = FPO.PO_NO
    WHERE FPODtl.[PO_STATUS] = 'Closed'
    AND FPODtl.[LINE_DOCK_DATE] <> 0;
```

Comment: It would be *extremely* helpful if you showed some of the numbers stored, and what date values you expect them to be.

Comment: Why do you refuse to use aliases? Is it fun typing `[BMDW].[dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl].` over and over again?

Comment: No, but I don't know any better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x NUMERIC(10,0);

SET @x = 20110501;

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), @x));
```

Result:

```
2011-05-01 00:00:00.000
```

To compare two:

```
DECLARE @x NUMERIC(10,0), @y NUMERIC(10,0);

SELECT @x = 20110501, @y = 20111019;

SELECT DATEDIFF
(
  DAY, 
  CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), @x)),
  CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), @y))
);
```

Result:

```
171
```

More importantly, fix the table. Stop storing dates as numbers. Store them as dates. If you get errors with this conversion, it's because your poor data choice has allowed bad data into the table. You can get around that - potentially - by writing the old version of `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF
(
  DAY, 
  CASE WHEN ISDATE(col1)=1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, col1) END,
  CASE WHEN ISDATE(col2)=1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, col2) END
)
FROM 
( 
  SELECT 
    col1 = CONVERT(CHAR(8), col1), 
    col2 = CONVERT(CHAR(8), col2)
  FROM dbo.table
) AS x;
```

This will produce nulls for any row where there is garbage in either column. Here is a modification to your original query:

```
SELECT
  [ITEM_NO] -- what table does this come from?
  ,[ITEM_DESC] -- what table does this come from?
  ,[HEADER_DUE_DATE] -- what table does this come from?
  ,D.WHS_SHORT_NAME AS [Warehouse] -- don't use single quotes for aliases!
  ,FPODtl.[PO_NO] AS [PO NUMBER]
  ,FPODtl.[PO_DATE] AS [Start]
  ,FPODtl.[PO_STATUS] AS [Status]
  ,FPODtl.[LINE_DOCK_DATE] AS [End]
  ,DATEDIFF
  (
    DAY,
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(CONVERT(CHAR(8), FPODtl.PO_DATE)) = 1
      THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), FPODtl.PO_DATE)) END,
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(CONVERT(CHAR(8), FPODtl.[LINE_DOCK_DATE])) = 1
      THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), FPODtl.[LINE_DOCK_DATE])) END
  )
FROM [dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl] AS FPODtl 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DS_tblDimWhs] AS D 
  ON FPODtl.WAREHOUSE = D.WAREHOUSE
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DS_tblFactPO] AS FPO 
  ON FPODtl.PO_NO = FPO.PO_NO
WHERE FPODtl.[PO_STATUS] = 'Closed'
AND FPODtl.[LINE_DOCK_DATE] <> 0;
```

Comment: I agree, that is my ultimate goal.  I just started here and it was the first thing I noticed and asked, "Why the eff are we storing dates as numerics?"  -- I'm a bit of a novice, but I realized that was bad.  I am going to just add a column for the correct datetime, but still need approval.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the additional input.  I'm trying to put the convert into the select and have it select the difference, but I am having no luck.  Just receive an error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." 

I put in 
    ,(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), [BWDW].[dbo].[DS_tblFactPODtl].[PO_DATE])) FROM dbo.DS_tblFactPODtl)

Comment: @shat did you see my update? It means you have bad data and you need to work around it.

Comment: Is there not a way I can work with the data that we have, should I just work on converting it now?

Comment: @shat yes I had already shown you a methodology you could use against your existing bad data. I just added even more information to you in case you couldn't use the query I posted and apply it to your case. But just because you *can* use tedious workarounds against your existing bad data doesn't mean you *should*. Solve the *problem*, not this one query.

Comment: First, thank you, that example provides data that works.  However, I definitely want to understand what I am missing here.  I appreciate the real-example on the use of Aliases.  I was reading some other material prior to seeing your update, but its much clearer seeing it with this.  As far as the cleaning up the bad data, I can use the second SELECT you posted above?  I am afraid to just modify everything now, but would like to possible add a column for testing on our test db.  If I understand, it checks for DATETIME, converts if not?

Comment: It makes sure that the string representation of the number can be safely converted to a datetime, yes.

Answer (score 2):

If the date stored as a number is like this: `20130226` for today, then the simpler way to convert to `DATE` or `DATETIME` would be:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),NumberDate),112)
```

Comment: I like your approach, but sample data would be very helpful, as LittleBobbyTables suggested. Otherwise, it could lead to ambiguity.

Comment: @MuhammadGhazi You are absolutely right about that. For a more precise answer we need to see a sample data

Comment: @lamak, I tried your suggestion and I am receiving: 

    The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: @shat stop trying things until you've actually told us a few numbers and what you expect them to convert to. Could you do that please so people stop posting guesses as answers?

Comment: @Aaron, I updated the initial question. The data is currently a NUMERIC field with YYYYMMDD content.  I am trying to count the number of days between two fields, but I figured first it would need to be converted to a proper DATETIME before I could do so..

Comment: @shat If that is the format of your date, then the conversion should be right. You most likely have dates that are either in a different format or simply number like this `20130230`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick formula to create a date from parts :

```
DateAdd( Month, (( @Year - 1900 ) * 12 ) + @Month - 1, @Day - 1 )
```

Simply use substrings from your original field to extract  `@Year`, `@Month` and `@Day`. For instance, if you have a numeric like `19531231` for december 31th, 1953, you could do :

```
DateAdd( Month, (( SubString(Cast(DateField As Varchar(8)), 1, 4) - 1900 ) * 12 ) + 
                   SubString(Cast(DateField As Varchar(8)), 5, 2) - 1, 
                   SubString(Cast(DateField As Varchar(8)), 7, 2) - 1 )
```

Comment: Like @Lamak's answer, this also makes some stretched assumptions about what the number looks like. Maybe it's number of seconds since epoch (or some other reference date). Maybe it's number of days since 1900 or since 2000.