# Get dates that are older than 30 dates from today

Tags: sql

I have such a situation. I have a field namely [IBLREC] that is of NUMERIC type.

I usually just do it this way and it works

```
    where cast(IBLREC as datetime) > DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
```

However, for some reason it doesn't work for this table(?)

I basically get zero results.

[Empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkvjY.jpg)

When I comment out this line, I do see that the column has results for older than 30 days from today.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, why it is not picking those dates up.

[When comment out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7qyl.jpg)

Can someone advise me anything?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can find a more detailed answere here: [Convert Date Stored as NUMERIC to DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098651/convert-date-stored-as-numeric-to-datetime)
(Including an explanation why you should not create a numeric-column for your dates)

Solution: To parse that numeric value you need to convert it as a text first, and then convert that text to a numeric value.

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), IBLREC), 112) > DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
AND IBLREC <> 0
```

Comment: thank you very much. It works!! I just have one question. When I comment out  AND IBLREC <> 0  I start getting an error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." Is there a way to have the same formula but also keep 0s?

Comment: The question is, what date does a "0" represent? Lets say the "0" represents 1980-01-01 (and you really want to get your hands dirty), it should work like this:
`WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ISNULL(NULLIF(@IBLREC, 0),19800101)), 112) > DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())`
The part `NULLIF(@IBLREC, 0)` sets the value to NULL if it is 0. And the `ISNULL(...)` part, converts a NULL to the given number 19800101(the 'date': 1980-01-01) - (or keeps the value if it is not NULL).

Comment: I have a question. I don't really have any nulls in this column. Is there a chance for me to convert '0' (not NULL) to '19800101'?

Comment: Sorry for not making that clear. Yes it is possible, and that above mentioned part allready does that. `ISNULL(NULLIF(@IBLREC, 0),19800101))`. It converts your "0" as a NULL and that 'new' NULL to your date 19800101